# Does dplyr::mutate() not recycle vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr

It seems as if creating a column with `dplyr::mutate()` does not allow vector recycling. Why?

Example:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 42), name = rep(letters[1:7], each = 6, times = 5))
```

now:

```
df %>% mutate (tp = c(1:42))  #results in 

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `tp` must be length 210 (the number of rows) or one, not 42
```

but of course

```
df$tp <- c(1:42) #works
```

Is my mutate code wrong or does recycling simply not work in `mutate()`?
If it helps, I am using `dplyr` 0.7.2 with RStudio 1.0.153 (Mac)

Comment: The error message makes it pretty clear you either have to specify all the values or one of them. No recycling.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, thanks. I just thought it might be possible but that my code was wrong. Sad times. No recycling.

Comment: If you need recyclying then as a workaround you can use `transform`.  Compare `BOD %>% transform(a = 1:2)` and `BOD %>% mutate(a = 1:2)` .

Comment: Thanks! @G.Grothendieck, transform is a great idea :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked two different questions:

- (title) "Does dplyr::mutate() not recycle vectors?"

A: no (as you found out). The [dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) makes it clear that recycling only works for length-1 vectors:

> They [vector values used in `mutate()`] must be either length 1 (they then get recycled) or have the same length as the number of rows.

- Why?

A: Probably impossible to answer without asking the `dplyr` developers. I would speculate that they reached a different conclusion about the tradeoff between convenience (on the one hand) and requiring explicit statements of user intentions (on the other hand) from the original developers of R (who even allowed *incomplete* recycling, albeit with a warning).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed two questions, good catch. Thanks a second time for answering both

Comment: I suspect that the difficulty of implementing recycling with a database backend may have contributed to this decision as well.

Answer (score 1):

**This is more a note then an answer:**

**Keypoint: Recycling in base R:**

1. **work** with `data.frame()`
2. **work not** with `data_frame()`
3. **work not** with `tibble()`

I just noticed that `df$tp <- c(1:42) #works` **does not work with tibbles**.

**So recycling does not work with a tibble but it works with a data frame!**

Today 26.11.2022 I tried to repeat the question:

Using:

`require(dplyr) df <- data_frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 42), name = rep(letters[1:7], each = 6, times = 5))`

I was given the warning to use `tibble` and not `data_frame()`.

1. With using `tibble` `df$tp <- c(1:42)` **did not work.**
2. Switching to using `data.frame` `df$tp <- c(1:42)` **worked.**

### data_frame():

data_frame is trimmed down version of data.frame that https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.0/topics/data_frame:

```
Never coerces inputs (i.e. strings stay as strings!).
Never addsrow.names.
Never munges column names.
Only recycles length 1 inputs.
Evaluates its arguments lazily and in order.
Addstbl_dfclass to output.
Automatically adds column names.
```